# Why is $\int_{\alpha}^{\alpha+T}f(x)\, dx=\int_\alpha^T f(x)\, dx+\int_T^{\alpha+T}f(x)\, dx$ true?

Tags: calculus

If $a<b<c$ we have $$\int_a^cf(x)\, dx=\int_a^bf(x)\, dx+\int_b^c f(x)\, dx\tag 1$$

But I have also seen 
$$\int_{\alpha}^{\alpha+T}f(x)\, dx=\int_\alpha^T f(x)\, dx+\int_T^{\alpha+T}f(x)\, dx \tag 2$$

**Q1:** In $(2)$, does it mean $f$ has to be periodic with $T$, i.e. $f(x+T)=f(x)$?

**Q1:** 
Is $(2)$ a special case of $(1)$, I can't see why?

In $(1)$ we have the inequality $a<b<c$, does it mean we have $\alpha<T<\alpha+ T$ in $(2)$?

Answer (score 0):

Following the doubts at the end of your question:  can you prove (2) if, say, $\alpha> T>0$ (which requires you to give meaning to $\int_\alpha^T f$).